# Basic .NET WebAPI hosted in AWS Lambda failing to construct controller

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, aws-lambda

I created a new .NET 6 WebAPI solution, with the default WeatherForecastController class. The only thing I changed in the project is to install Amazon.AspNetCoreLambda.Hosting, and add the following line in my Program.cs file:

```
builder.Services.AddAWSLambdaHosting(LambdaEventSource.HttpApi);
```

I built the solution, zipped the files, and deployed it to an AWS Lambda. The error I'm getting in the logs is:

```
System.MissingMethodException: Cannot dynamically create an instance of type 'Example.Controllers.WeatherForecastController'. Reason: No parameterless constructor defined.
```

The controller is unchanged and looks like this:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace Example.Controllers;

[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
{
    private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
    {
        "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
    };

    private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;

    public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [HttpGet(Name = "GetWeatherForecast")]
    public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
    {
        return Enumerable.Range(1, 5)
            .Select(
                index => new WeatherForecast
                {
                    Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
                    TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
                    Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
                })
            .ToArray();
    }
}
```

The Program.cs file looks like this:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddAWSLambdaHosting(LambdaEventSource.HttpApi);

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

The AWS Lambda is set up with the following configuration:

- Hander:  `Example::Example.Controllers.WeatherForecastController::Get`
- Runtime: `dotnet6`

Runtime: dotnet6

I can't see what step I'm missing as I've been following tutorials online and can't get it to work.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You specified the handler name as `Example::Example.Controllers.WeatherForecastController::Get`, which points to the GET endpoint method in the weather controller. However, to serve the WEB API, you must let the lambda function execute the `Program.cs` file first so that all the necessary services will be properly configured.

Therefore, to host a .NET Core Web API in the lambda function, you have to set the **assembly name** of your application in the `handler` section. In your case, it should be `Example`.

p.s. Based on your controller namespace, I assume that the assembly name of your application is `Example`. However, if you use a different assembly name, make sure to use that name in the `handler` section instead.

Answer (score -2):

Your error message states that there is no parameterless constructor defined. So let's create one! Here is an example:

```
public WeatherForecastController()
{
    // This constructor can be empty or initialize any required fields.
}
```

When using dependency injection in ASP.NET Core, the framework requires a parameterless constructor to instantiate the controller. In your code, you only have a constructor that takes an ILogger parameter.

You can instantiate a parameterless constructor in this controller while still setting up that logger no problem.

Add this line under the `.AddControllers()` line:

```
builder.Services.AddLogging();
```

This should take care of your error! Hope this helps.